# SCP Progress bar like WGET in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, centos, ubuntu-12.04, sh

I have folder named `testfolder` which contain some files in it my machine. And I want copy this folder to a remote machine using `scp` command as given below.

```
scp -P 6969 testfolder user@remotemachine:/path/to/destination
```

Here I need to display a progress bar something like we get when using `wget` command as given below.

```
[ =============48%                           ]
```

How can I implement using a bash shell script. Please advice me as I am very beginner inn shell scripting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [pv](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/quickref/pv.shtml)

Some examples [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/pv-command-examples/)

Comment: `pv` works if your data goes through a `|` pipe.  With `scp` data is not really going through a pipe.